# Accessing maps google maps object in react-google-maps library

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

In my react app by using react-google-maps library, I'm trying to access google maps object calling constructor in line 32 but I get "google is not defined" error.
This library does not expose maps object, How can i access google objects ? It is also not included in props

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import flicker from '../assets/flicker.svg';
import axios from 'axios';
import { compose, withProps } from 'recompose';
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from 'react-google-maps';

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&callback=initMap`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => {
  console.log(props.google);
  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={3} defaultCenter={{ lat: 46, lng: 2 }}>
      {props.datas.map(data => (
        <Marker
          key={data.countryInfo._id}
          position={{ lat: data.countryInfo.lat, lng: data.countryInfo.long }}
          defaultLabel={data.cases}
          icon={{
            url: flicker,
            size: new google.maps.Size(15, 25), ### HERE ###
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
});

const CoronaMap = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries?yesterday=0&sort=cases')
      .then(res => setData(res.data));
  }, []);

  return <MyMapComponent datas={data} />;
};

export default CoronaMap;
```

but In documentation, google object is accessible https://prnt.sc/tx78tf

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the issue in my end. Line 32 is properly working on my end however can see some things that you need to fix in the code you provided.

1. Remove the `&callback=initMap` in the Google Maps script inside the `googleMapURL` since there's no `initMap` function in your code.
2. Make sure that you are not using the same value in your keys. It looks like there are two `null` values for `data.countryInfo._id` and this throw a warning in your code. You can also use index instead to make sure that the value of your `key` is unique. You can do this by using the following code:

```
{props.datas.map((data,index) => (
        <Marker
          key={index}
```

3. The label of the Marker only accept string values and it seems that the value of`{data.cases}` is not a string. You need to convert this value to string in order to use this data. You can do it by using  `{data.cases.toString()}` or  `{JSON.stringify(data.cases)}`.

Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/coronamap-using-mappeddata-kja5w1?file=index.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer, I solved it by adding window keyword "new window.google.maps.Size(15, 25)". things you offered did not work either. It is weird :D